# How to open Windows 8.1 taskmgr as summary mode?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, task-manager

In the `Windows 8.1 > Taskmgr > Performance tab`, you can double click on the left panel and make it shown as a small window, containing the system usage summary:

https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2472-task-manager-show-summary-view-compact-mode-windows-8-a.html

I want to know how to make taskmgr automatically open in this mode?

I already made a shortcut to the startup folder so taskmgr will run minimized every time I login, but this mode is perfect to replace my nice old gadget.